# How to send two response for a single post request in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, httpresponse, jsonresponse

I am processing a video in backend but it's taking some time so I am looking for a way by which I can send the process time first and after it's completion I can send the video url.

I tried using HttpResponse.write() but it didn't send the response. I got response only after the completion  of whole process.

Comment: Share the current code that you are trying.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need async method and use something like websocket.